# Stop Notification from firing every time app starts

Tags: android

i have a notification with a broadcast service and i have defined my notification in my main activity's oncreate but the problem is the notification fires again and again each time i open main activity. it is supposed to fire only according to the set time.

```
 // Fire Notification from ReceiverReminder
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReceiverReminder.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    long recurring = (1 * 60000 * 60 * 24); // in milliseconds
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, Calendar.getInstance()
            .getTimeInMillis(), recurring, sender);
    //
```

Comment: if you write your code in onCreate it will execute all the time you open while you open your code. refactor it on any method and set alarm like in a button click.

Answer (score 2):

Read the description of *setRepeating method* in [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))
According to it the parameters are:

> - **type**  -    One of ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC, or    RTC_WAKEUP.
> - **triggerAtMillis** -  time in milliseconds that the alarm    should first go off, using the appropriate clock (depending on the    alarm type).
> - **intervalMillis** -   interval in milliseconds between    subsequent repeats of the alarm.
> - **operation** -    Action to perform when the    alarm goes off; typically comes from IntentSender.getBroadcast().

Now you are passing the current time as the second parameter, telling it to fire immediately, and then repeat itself every 1 * 60000 * 60 * 24 millis.

If you want the alarm to fire for the first time after 1 * 60000 * 60 * 24 millis, the change your method to:

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, Calendar.getInstance()
        .getTimeInMillis() + recurring, recurring, sender);
```

**Edit:**

Based on your comments, you shouldn't *reset* the alarm every time the activity is opened. So you should save your state somewhere, for example in a variable in SharedPreferences. So your code should insted be somewhat like this:

```
boolean areAlarmsAlreadySet = ...// get boolean variable from SharedPreferences
if (!areAlarmsAlreadySet)
{
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReceiverReminder.class);
   PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

   AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this
        .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   long recurring = (1 * 60000 * 60 * 24); // in milliseconds
   am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, Calendar.getInstance()
        .getTimeInMillis() + recurring, recurring, sender);

 // set the variable in SharedPreferences to true
}
```

Comment: i am trying to fire it every 24 hrs

Comment: i have three services with notification of its own, one should fire it every 24 hrs, other ones 3 days and 7 days

Comment: im not getting it. why did you put those three dots in your answer? where is the sharedpreferences?

Comment: "..." where meant to signify that you had to write extra code yourself.  Read here about SharedPreferences, and how to use it to persist data http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 0):

```
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getContext(), 0, intent, 0);
  //After after 30 seconds
 alarmManager2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, twopm.getTimeInMillis(), 30*1000 , alarmIntent);
```

And

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: what do both of the parts do? where do i put the first one?? any explanation?